# Display Date in Block in Customer's Timezone

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to display a date I have a store in a custom table in UTC format in a block; I need to display this date in the customer's timezone (it is an expected delivery date).

What is the proper way to do this in Magento?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this

```
protected $timezone;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
    ......
    )
    {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
    }
    
    $dateTimeZone = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($yourdate))->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the Timezoneinterface and it is working fine.

Comment: please accept the ans if this works for you so that other can find it